# How to solve the error during the conversion between FFmpeg's avframe and OpenCV's mat?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

I made the conversion between FFmpeg's avframe and OpenCV's mat. But the following code doesn't convert the mat format to avframe format correctly. The first part converts avframe to mat format and the second part converts mat to avframe format.

Here is my source code:

```
AVFrame* ProcessFrame(AVFrame *frame, int stream_index)
{
 //first part
    AVStream *in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index];
    AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx = in_stream->codec;

    AVFrame  *pFrameRGB = NULL;

    struct SwsContext * img_convert_ctx = NULL;
    if(img_convert_ctx == NULL){
        img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                                         pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                                         AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    pFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc();
    int size = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

    uint8_t  *out_bufferRGB = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(size);

    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, out_bufferRGB, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

    sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);

    Mat imageFrame = Mat(pCodecCtx->height, pCodecCtx->width, CV_8UC3, out_bufferRGB);    

    delete[] out_bufferRGB;

   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //second part starts

    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, imageFrame.data,AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

    struct SwsContext * convert_ctx = NULL;
    if(convert_ctx == NULL){
        convert_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                                         AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                                         pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }

    AVFrame *srcFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    size = avpicture_get_size(pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

    uint8_t  *out_buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(size);

    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)srcFrame, out_buffer, pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

    sws_scale(convert_ctx, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, srcFrame->data, srcFrame->linesize);

    delete[] out_buffer;
    av_free(pFrameRGB);

    srcFrame->width = frame->width;
    srcFrame->height = frame->height;
    srcFrame->format = frame->format;

    av_frame_copy_props(srcFrame, frame);

    return srcFrame;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what doesn't work. Is it conversion to or from that doesn't work? What is the error exactly? Please provide a minimal, complete piece of code that can be compiled and run.

Comment: *"not the same"*? Black? Wrong colours? Distorted shapes? Pieces missing? Totally unrecognisable junk? Unplayable?

Comment: The produced video is not the same as the original video.

Comment: There is a grey strip across the middle of the video. And some frames are broken.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I remove the del statement to make it work.

```
AVFrame* ProcessFrame(AVFrame *frame, int stream_index)
{
 //first part
    AVStream *in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index];
    AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx = in_stream->codec;

    AVFrame  *pFrameRGB = NULL;

    struct SwsContext * img_convert_ctx = NULL;
    if(img_convert_ctx == NULL){
        img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                                         pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                                         AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    pFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc();
    int size = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

    uint8_t  *out_bufferRGB = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(size);

    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, out_bufferRGB, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

    sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);

    Mat imageFrame = Mat(pCodecCtx->height, pCodecCtx->width, CV_8UC3, out_bufferRGB);   

   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //second part starts

    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, imageFrame.data,AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

    struct SwsContext * convert_ctx = NULL;
    if(convert_ctx == NULL){
        convert_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                                         AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                                         pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }

    AVFrame *srcFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    size = avpicture_get_size(pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

    uint8_t  *out_buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(size);

    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)srcFrame, out_buffer, pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

    sws_scale(convert_ctx, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, srcFrame->data, srcFrame->linesize);

    av_free(pFrameRGB);

    srcFrame->width = frame->width;
    srcFrame->height = frame->height;
    srcFrame->format = frame->format;

    av_frame_copy_props(srcFrame, frame);

    return srcFrame;
}
```